# How to install CAB file /noui on Windows Embedded Compact 7 during Unsupported System Version?

Tags: compact-framework, cab, windows-embedded

I have almost tried everything, I can not install the file without requiring user interaction (what is necessary). Is there any why to pass through it? I tried to run

```
wceload /noui /silent /delete 0 path\to\sql.wce5.armv4i.CAB
```

which gives me no error but It does not install the CAB file, I think it's because it don't want to go through the message about "Unsupported System Version" (without /noui parameter)
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4U3Zm.jpg).

Also I need to install SQL Server Compact Edition in v3.5.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: a) you need to provide a 'compatible' cab

Comment: b) do not allow the user to specify a custom dir. This is done by removing %InstDir% references in the cab file

SQL CE is part of the platform builder. Therefor you normally need the OEM to include this or install WCE7 platform builder to be able to get the SQL support file: http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/entryid/230/Compact-7-Getting-Started-Part-6-Develop-SQL-Compact-Database-Application

Comment: SQL Server Compact made a lot of problems in my company. We switched to Sqlite. It runs in Compact Framework 3.5 / Win CE / Win Mob. Think about it ;) I assume you do not have a sql.wce5...cab? In a CAB-file there is a min OS-Version and a max. OS-Version. If you have a tool for editing the CAB you could change the max. OS-Version to "9.99" and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to change the min and max version of a cab file. You should set the max version to 9.99 and then the unsupported message disappears. This would be one solution.